# regex for exact "namespaces"

Tags: javascript, regex

So I want to write a JS regex that can match Salesforce username (I said namespace in the title because it would be a more common use case for the same solution).

Example Users:

```
user1@myexample.com
user1@myexample.com.sandbox
user1@myexample.com.UT
```

I struggling to come up with a good regex that will match `user1@myexample.com` but not `user1@myexample.com.sandbox`.

The typical solution for matching whole words:

```
new RegExp("\\buser1@myexample.com\\b", "g");
```

does not work because `.` is a word break.

The regex needs to find the User anywhere in a file, but it will **NEVER** have a period at the end (EXAMPLE: user1@myexample.com.sandbox.)

I'm sure there is a simple solution, but my regex is pretty lousy and I'm stuck.

Comment: `user1@myexample.com\b(?!\.sandbox)`?

Comment: @minitech that would still match on the .UT.  Plus I have no idea what subspaces i will come across

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `user1@myexample\.com(?!\.)`. It makes sure that there is no period after the com. This works with the cases you provided.

Comment: Ahhh i knew it was simple! I actually tried something similar but I had (?!\.*) so it wasn't matching anything.  Thanks

Comment: No problem. Escaping is easy to forget but makes a huge difference.